# Search html text with html tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to search some text which can search with or without html tag. Have tried with `(?!([^<]+)?>)` which is working with content which is outside of html tag.

Regex - `(simple html)(?!([^<]+)?>)`

Html - `This is simple html text <span class='simple'>simple html</span> text simple <p>html</p>`

but the content in `simple <p>html</p>` is not working.

Please note i am avoiding `class='simple'`.

Comment: [You shouldn't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3660134)

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this... please share the sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: please provide code

Comment: @gurvinder372 can be checked in https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/145

Comment: @santanu Can you share the sample inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Using: `/<\/?.*?>/g` and replace, you can strip out all HTML tags, and simply search through the remaining text.

```js
let regex = /<\/?.*?>/g,
  html = `This is simple html text <span class='simple'>simple html</span> text simple <p>html</p>`,
  string = html.replace(regex, "");

console.log(`Stripped HTML: ${string}`)

let find = "simple html",
  found = string.search(find);

console.log(`\n$ String "${find}" found at char ${found}`)
```